# Show back button with getSupportActionBar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So, I've this little activity and I want to add a back button (**the standard arrow one**) I search for the answers here and I found this little code:

```
public class PozosFluyentes extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pozos_fluyentes);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
            finish();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This crash my app, so anyone could help me with this please! I know is something pretty usual but I new to android development. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please attach the crash logs here so we can identify real problem.

Comment: Hi Avi, the debug doesn't show, me any error the applications just close itself as expected when I remove the code it works perfectly. Again I'm new to android, I'm running the app directly on my phone, so is there any way to show the crash log please let me know.

Comment: @ Alex Llanez, @ Avi means the Logcat logs.

Comment: You probably don't have a view with id 'toolbar' in your layout 'R.layout.activity_pozos_fluyentes'.

Comment: Yes @AlexLlanez...make sure you have a ToolBar in your R.layout.activity_pozos_fluyentes...that is the problem of your App crash.

Comment: remove 
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); and I hope you are using Toolbar for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably you add an `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and not using a Theme that includes `NoActionBar`. `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` like theme will fix the issue. But if it does not, share your xml, styles.xml and logcat to check error. With little info the first thing to look is this. Also you can check  [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-Toolbar) and see you need to disable theme provided ActionBar

Comment: You are using Toolbar in layout file. But in your styles you may not be using a theme with NoActionBar which means you are trying to add 2 Actionbars. One provided by your theme another is the Toolbar. Change your theme and check if it crashes and if it does share logcat.

Comment: the default drawer theme has one toolbar on it, I was duplicating it with the code, Just delete that part and works fine! Thank you for the info on two toolbars

Comment: If you have deleted `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` from your layout instead of changing your theme, it's not wrong, but you disregard a more flexible and customizable Toolbar. If you want to have Material Design in your apps, support and design library widgets are the widgets to be used. Also, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replcae your code with below.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

if (actionBar!= null) { // you have to use actionBar (ActionBar Object)  instead.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
   }
```

let me know it working or not.....Hope this will helps you...(:

Comment: Hi Sagar, unfortunately changing my code to this does not work, my app still crashes trying to get from my main activity to the one with the code, thanks for your reply!